# Get data from JSON to D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I tried `d.bubbledata.values.value` or `d.bubbledata.values[0].value`, but didn't get result.

How can I get all properties of value?

My code is:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll(".bubble")
        .data(json)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class","bubble")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return d.bubbledata.values[0].value;
        })
```

and my json is:

```
 {
          "categories": [
            "2003",
            "2004"
          ],
"bubbledata": {
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "346462",
        "name": "blabla1",
        "color": "#3a3790",
        "bordercolor": "#3a3790",
        "value": 0.82908,
        "label": 9.2942
      },
      {
        "id": "346131",
        "name": "blabla2",
        "color": "#ea772a",
        "bordercolor": "#ea772a",
        "value": 0.26954,
        "label": 3.0216
      }
 ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the data passed to the `data()` function.

In D3, `data()` accepts three things:

1. An array
2. A function
3. Nothing

Thus, you cannot pass an object, as you're doing right now. You have to pass an **array** to `data`:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll(".bubble")
    .data(json.bubbledata.values)//this is an array
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class","bubble")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.value;//the "value" in each object
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to add to the above. If somebody use "forceCollide", you must add `JSON.parse()`. For example `return JSON.parse(d.somevalue)`.